# Можно ли отследить на JS что пользователь пишет в чат в другом iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

На сайте есть чат который отображается в Iframe и находится на другом домене. Нужно любым способом предостеречь написание мата в чат. API чата не позволяет этого делать. На js пробовал onkeyup , не срабатывает в iframe, возможно ли как то отследить что пользователь пишет в чат и если мат(функционал есть) то скрывать чат?)

Comment: Политика безопасности не позволит. если on keyup к документу срабатывает - то можно попробовать запретить нажатие следующего символа, но в таком случае подойдет keydown, так как keyup срабатывает после того как символ уже введен

Answer (score 1):

Невозможно управлять элементами с помощью js внутри iframe, если только этот самый js-код не внутри него.